# R - conditionally replace rows in data table

Tags: r, replace, data.table, rows

I am trying to conditionally replace row values in a data table.
Please consider the following dataset excerpt:

```
library(data.table)
txt1 <- "Date Location Measurement Scenario         Var Month    Decade
  1960-01-01  4100103        23.3  CRU3.2 Temperature   Jan 1960-1990
  1960-02-01  4100103        24.1  CRU3.2 Temperature   Feb 1960-1990
  1960-03-01  4100103        23.6  CRU3.2 Temperature   Mar 1960-1990
  1960-04-01  4100103        20.4  CRU3.2 Temperature   Apr 1960-1990
  1960-05-01  4100103        16.2  CRU3.2 Temperature   May 1960-1990
  1960-06-01  4100103        16.5  CRU3.2 Temperature   Jun 1960-1990"

dt <- data.table(read.table(textConnection(txt1), header=TRUE))
```

This is just a sample. My actual data has about 2.5 million rows.

As you can see, I have temperature measurements for multiple locations.
However, the locations are identified with geocode instead of names, which is not very readable.

Therefore, I have another dataset that relates geocode and city name:

```
txt2 <- "GEOCODIG_M, Name
4100103,              Abatiá
4100202,        Adrianópolis
4100301,       Agudos do Sul
4100400, Almirante Tamandaré
4100459,  Altamira do Paraná
4100509,             Altônia"

df <- read.csv(textConnection(txt2),sep=',', header=TRUE)
```

So, what I need to do is compare the field `Location` in `dt` to `GEOCODIG_M` in `df` and replace geocode by name.

The expected outcome for this case would be:

```
        Date    Name Measurement Scenario         Var Month    Decade
  1960-01-01  Abatiá        23.3  CRU3.2 Temperature   Jan 1960-1990
  1960-02-01  Abatiá        24.1  CRU3.2 Temperature   Feb 1960-1990
  1960-03-01  Abatiá        23.6  CRU3.2 Temperature   Mar 1960-1990
  1960-04-01  Abatiá        20.4  CRU3.2 Temperature   Apr 1960-1990
  1960-05-01  Abatiá        16.2  CRU3.2 Temperature   May 1960-1990
  1960-06-01  Abatiá        16.5  CRU3.2 Temperature   Jun 1960-1990
```

What is the best way to do this using data tables?

Comment: Fyi, you can also use `fread(txt1)`. The merge-assign here is pretty standard: `dt[df, on=c(Location="GEOCODIG_M"), Name := i.Name ]`

Comment: @Frank thanks for your suggestion. However, when trying this on my actual data, I get an error: `Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  x.'Location' is a factor column being joined to i.'GEOCODIG_M' which is type 'integer'. Factor columns must join to factor or character columns.` How could I adapt your code to overcome this?

Comment: You can overwrite the column in both places before merging like `DT[, Location := as.character(Location)]` and `df$GEOCODIG_M = as.character(df$GEOCODIG_M)`

Comment: That worked, thanks! Would you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. I think the marked dupe pretty well covers it, but if you disagree, I'll unmark the dupe and post another answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go about this.

You could simply make a new "Name" variable, using `match` to find the matching row in `txt2`.

```
txt1$Name <- txt2$Name[match(txt1$Location, txt2$GEOCODIG_M)]
```

Or, you could merge the two datasets

```
txt3 <- merge(txt1, txt2, by.x = 'Location', by.y = 'GEOCODIG_M', all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not create any other table because my original one is 1.5GB in RAM size. This is why I'd rather to stick to a data table solution.